# Functional Javascript example of higher-order functions using plucker, reduce and finder functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, reduce, higher-order-functions

I'm going through the book Functional Javascript by Michael Fogus. In chapter 4, he creates a function, titled finder, which utilizes reduce. I'm having difficulty grasping the implementation of this function...

```
function finder(valueFun, bestFun, coll){
    return _.reduce(coll, function(best, current){
        var bestValue = valueFun(best);
        var currentValue = valueFun(current);

        return (bestValue === bestFun(bestValue, currentValue)) ? best : current;
    });
}
```

(Note that he uses the Underscore.js library in his book)

Anyways, he uses the finder-function in the following example:

```
var people = [{name: "Fred", age: 65}, {name: "Lucy", age: 36}];

**finder(plucker('age'), Math.max, people);**
```

Where the plucker function is defined as:

```
function plucker(field){
    return function(obj){
        return (obj && obj[field]);
    }
}
```

(plucker is supposed to return the value of a key)

I'm going through the code line by line, but I'm struggling when I come across the reduce-function w/in the finder-function definition. What I don't understand is

```
valueFun(best)
```

and
    valueFun(current)

what are the values of best and current, respectively, with each iteration through the reduce-function? My understanding is that valueFun is the plucker function. But he gives plucker the argument 'age' already, so then what does best and current represent?

If you're answering this, I'd really appreciate if you outlined how you arrive at your answer so that I see the values going through the finder function step by step. THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that new JavaScript coders struggle with is how often functions get passed around, both as arguments to other functions and as returns from other functions.

> My understanding is that valueFun is the plucker function.

Not quite. When he invokes `finder(plucker('age'), Math.max, people);` the first argument to `finder` is the *result* of `plucker('age')`. In effect, this is the function `function(obj){ return (obj && obj['age']);}`

To make this a bit more explicit, we could do something like this:

```
    var ageGetter = plucker('age');
    finder(ageGetter, Math.max, people);
```

So essentially `plucker('age')` (valueFun) is just a function that returns the `age` property of an object. `bestFun` is the Math.max function, which just returns the higher of two numbers. In each iteration of the `_.reduce` function, he's comparing the `age` value of the current object with the highest existing value and returning the greater of the two.

If it's not covered in that book, you'll want to read about closures in JavaScript, as that is extremely relevant to this example.